# Make Thunderbird mark thread as read

Tags: email, thunderbird

Thunderbird sometimes manages to recognize a group of emails as a reply chain. One example is its treatment of GitHub notifications within the same issue. This collapses every email in there into the message pane. However, It only marks the first one as read. Is there a way to automatically mark all of them as read when I click on the group of items in the message list pane?

Answer (score 0):

I just checked this by a Thunderbird v102.11.2 (Linux):

- If the grouped mail thread is collapsed you can mark the line and hit <kbd>m</kbd> — This will mark all mails in this group as read respectively as unread, depending on the state of the top mail (oldest one).
- If the group is not collapsed, you've to mark mails of the thread to change their state to read/unread by one hit on <kbd>m</kbd>.

Collapsing a thread group has the effect that every item of the group is selected when the sole visible one gets selected.

*=> I cannot reproduce your problem. This feature works as it is expected (also by you).*
=> You should provide more details, so we can reproduce or better understand your problem.

---

> Thunderbird sometimes manages to recognize a group of emails as a reply chain.

This will happen if the answering one uses the <kbd>Reply</kbd> button to do this. Then the header keys `Message-ID` and later on `Reference` will be maintained and enable the thread view.

---

##### Update:

> what I want to do is automatically read the collapsed grouped thread as read whenever I click on its entry in the message list just like other non-threaded emails. I do not want to manually mark as read each thread.

Thank you for these details. You obviously would like to also apply the  feature *"Automatically mark messages as read"* to the whole collapsed thread.

[image]

Unfortunately when a thread is collapsed *no Mail content will be displayed in the message pane* (only their first fey lines). — This is the reason why not even the topmost message of the collapsed thread group gets marked as read automatically.

What you can do is to

- select the message by targeting the "read/not-read" marker, when selecting the collapsed thread group by mouse. OR
- when selecting the message by keyboard additionally hit <kbd>m</kbd>.

These two options will mark the whole collapsed thread group as read (if the topmost message is currently "not read", else its vice versa).

[image] The "Message read/not-read" signal in the message list pane that can be clicked to change state.

---

> Is there a way to automatically mark all of them as read when I click on the group of items in the message list pane?

AFAIK, there is no option present in Thunderbird that will enable the requested functionality.

If you are not satisfied with given possibilities of the software, you can

- [Create a Thunderbird Add-on](https://developer.thunderbird.net/add-ons/about-add-ons) that implements the functionality.
- [Create a feature request](https://connect.mozilla.org/t5/ideas/idb-p/ideas/label-name/thunderbird/tab/most-kudoed) to ask the developers of Thunderbird to implement it.
- Check for a fork of Thunderbird to see if they have this feature implemented or ask them to do so. I.e. [Betterbird](https://www.betterbird.eu/) tries to implement features that they think are useful and they miss in Thunderbird.

Comment: Again, what I want to do is automatically read the collapsed grouped thread as read whenever I click on its entry in the message list just like other non-threaded emails. I do not want to manually mark as read each thread.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the detail that is important to you. Preferably you might want to update your question by this for others reading your question.

Comment: It's already there. "Is there a way to automatically mark all of them as read when I click on the group of items in the message list pane?" The solution you gave is not a solution at all. I am satisfied with the collapsed display. Thanks for identifying the feature though.

Comment: Well, this is a matter of *Works as designed*. For the functionality you request, the developers of Thunderbird decided to handle it differently than you would like to have it. — The answer is to *implement the functionality in Thunderbird*. This can be done by requesting this feature at the developers or writing an add-on or changing the software to a fork of Thunderbird. i.e. see [Betterbird](https://www.betterbird.eu/). Perhaps you can as them to implement your feature.

Comment: Updated the answer.